# Redirect traffic to https

Tags: apache-2.2

I need to redirect the following instances to https://www.mydomain.com;

- mydomain.com
- www.mydomain.com
- http://www.mydomain.com

I have the following in my .htaccess already, but this only redirects mydomain.com to https://www.mydomain.com;

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..+$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Grateful if anyone could perhaps tell me what I need to add. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the second RewriteCond so you filter ONLY on the https status, and not anything to do with the requested host. That'll make it an unconditional redirect, regardless of how the site was requested